# Find Breakpoint with optimr

Tags: r, optimization, non-linear-regression

I'm trying to fit a known function to data points, finding the best parameters settings. For that purpose I'm using the `optimr` package.

Here's a reproducible example:

```
packages = c("optimr", "ggplot2", "tidyverse")
lapply(packages, library, character.only=T)

testfun <- function(par, x){
 case_when(
  x < par[1] ~ par[2]*x,
  x >= par[1] ~ par[3] + par[4]*x^2)
}

optfun <- function(par, x, y){
 sum((testfun(par, x) - y)^2)
}

optout <- optimr(par = c(20000,0,0,0), optfun, x = ggplot2::midwest$popdensity, y = ggplot2::midwest$poptotal, method = "L-BFGS-B")

ggplot(ggplot2::midwest, aes(x = popdensity, y = poptotal)) + 
 geom_point() +
 stat_function(fun = testfun, args = list(par = optout$par))
```

I can fit a simple function and the setup will find the best fitting parameters. But `par[1]` does not change and simply stays on the initial value when i introduce a piecewise function.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Piecewise functions, especially piecewise functions with flat parts, will give optimisers trouble. Optimisers will generally give up on a parameter if the function value doesnt' change for some step size, and might not search far enough to hit the step.

Look for other parameters to `optimr` that might widen the search space.

Comment: Thanks! I checked and fiddling with `optimr(..., controls = list(parscale = c(1, 200,...))` gets me a better result already. However, this would mean that I need to calibrate this manually?